# Client can’t connect to OpenVPN server behind a separate VPN

Tags: debian, openvpn

First time poster, I hope I am in the right place.

Current situation: 
In my home network, I have OpenVPN Server on raspi4 running Debian 10 (raspbian buster) and on the same device I want to enable Windscribe VPN. However when I enable windscribe VPN, the Openvpn clients can not connect to the OpenVPN server. I am using ufw with iptables and have forwarded tun0 (openvpn traffic) to eth0 using masquerade . When windscribe vpn is disabled, the clients are able to access the openvpn server without any issues.

My DDNS for the OpenVPN is pointing to the home network IP, so I thought that my router/gateway should direct my openvpn clients to my server on my LAN via port forwarding but that does not seem to work. When windscribe vpn is enabled, the client connection is timed out. I am not sure why.

I have tried to update the DDNS to point to the new IP from windscribe but that doesn’t work as there is no port forwarding on their end without an additional fee.

What I want to accomplish:
I want to protect my OpenVPN server by using windscribe vpn because all the traffic from the clients is routed through the server. I am using OpenVPN so the clients can access my samba shares as well as access geo-restricted content.

Is there a way to get this to work and/or a better way to have this setup? Currently windscribe does not support split tunneling, but is there a way that I can route OpenVPN traffic to bypass the windscribe vpn and establish a connection?

I can share server/client ovpns if needed.

Comment: I am thinking I need to route my tun0 (vpn server) traffic through tun1 (windscribe vpn) to be able to get this to work. Has anyone had experience with creating the forwarding rules for this?